# How to correctly use pandas agg function when running groupby on a column of type timestamp/datetime/datetime64?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, count, aggregate

I'm trying to understand why calling count() directly on a group returns the correct answer (in this example, 2 rows in that group), but calling count via a lambda in the agg() function returns the beginning of epoch ("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002").

```
# Using groupby(lambda x: True) in the code below just as an illustrative example.
# It will always create a single group.
x = DataFrame({'time': [np.datetime64('2005-02-25'), np.datetime64('2006-03-30')]}).groupby(lambda x: True)

display(x.count())
>>time
>>True  2

display(x.agg(lambda x: x.count()))
>>time
>>True  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
```

Could this be a bug in pandas? I am using
Pandas version: 0.16.1
IPython version: 3.1.0
numpy version: 1.9.2

I get the same result regardless of whether I use the standard python datetime vs np.datetime64 vs the pandas Timestamp.

EDIT (as per the accepted answer from @jeff, it looks like I may need to coerce to dtype object before applying an aggregation function that doesn't return a datetime type):

```
dt = [datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1)] * 2
x = DataFrame({'time': dt})
x['time2'] = x['time'].astype(object)
display(x)
y = x.groupby(lambda x: True)
y.agg(lambda x: x.count())

>>time  time2
>>True  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here x is the original frame from above (not with your groupby). Passing a UDF, e.g. the lambda, calls this on each Series. So this is the result of the function.

```
In [35]: x.count()
Out[35]: 
time    2
dtype: int64
```

Then coercion to the original dtype of the Series happens. So the result is:

```
In [36]: Timestamp(2)
Out[36]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002')
```

which is exactly what you are seeing. The point of the coercion to the original dtype is to preserve it if at all possible. Not doing this would be even more magic on the groupby results.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I coerce the datetime64 to dtype object then it aggregates as intended. Is that the most reasonable way to deal with this issue? Presumably I'm losing some performance by casting to object in this way, but I'm not sure what a good alternative would be.

Comment: well, what aggregation are you doing? from a groupby with ``datetime64[ns]``. I can't think of much that we don't have defined already (or that you would first operate on the frame and do something).

Comment: I am checking for rows that have missing values, but there's no function for that, so I have to do (len - count()), so I pass a list of functions to agg(). E.G. x.groupby(lambda x: True).agg(['count', len]). If I leave the column type as a datetime, the len function's output is coerced to a datetime.

Comment: Alternatively, I could convert the output of my custom aggregation functions to floats before returning them (at which point pandas doesn't try to coerce them back into datetimes)

Comment: and ``df.isnull()`` doesn't do it for you? This is very odd to groupby on everything and do a count like this.

Comment: `df.isnull().sum()` would be great if you were just trying to get the null counts, but it's a common case to want to know the fraction of nulls (for instance, to decide whether there is enough missing data to throw an exception). One **could** use `df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum()/float(len(x)))` for that case, but it's also useful to see stats at various levels of aggregation, so using groupby makes for a more uniform treatment. If you have several summary stats you want to gather (e.g. `len`), you need to pass in a list of functions to `groupby().agg()`. Like writing your own `describe()`

Comment: you know you can pass ``.describe()`` to a groupby. or use several functions with ``.agg``. but always choose the vectorized approach first. ``.apply`` with a UDF should be last on the list.