# Pandas groupby datetime function does not preserve dtype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having trouble extracting the `.minute` property of a Pandas datetime object, in the context of a `groupby` aggregation.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929585/how-to-correctly-use-pandas-agg-function-when-running-groupby-on-a-column-of-typ) appears to touch on the same root issue, but the accepted answer just explained why the problem was happening (which is fair, as the OP only asked to understand the problem).  I'm posting now because I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't rely on explicitly changing the type of the data I'm aggregating.

Here's some example code:

```
import pandas as pd
ids = ['a','a','b','b']
dates = ['2017-01-01 01:01:00','2017-01-01 01:02:00',
         '2017-03-03 01:03:00','2017-03-03 01:04:00']
dates = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'datetime':dates})

  id             datetime     
0  a  2017-01-01 01:01:00
1  a  2017-01-01 01:02:00
2  b  2017-03-03 01:03:00
3  b  2017-03-03 01:04:00
```

My goal is to group by `id`, and then extract the minute, as an integer value, of the earliest timestamp in each `datetime` group.

For example, to do this across *all* `datetime` values, this works:

```
df.datetime.min().minute  # returns 1
```

I want to mimic that same functionality in a `groupby()` setting.
Combining `min()` and `.minute` in a UDF, however, the minute value gets tacked onto the end of a datetime that marks the start of the Unix epoch:

```
def get_earliest_minute(tstamps):
    return tstamps.min().minute

df.groupby('id').agg({'datetime':get_earliest_minute})

                         datetime
id  
 a  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
 b  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
```

The type returned from `get_earliest_minute()` is an integer:

```
def get_earliest_minute(tstamps):
    return type(tstamps.min().minute)

df.groupby('id').agg({'datetime':get_earliest_minute})

        datetime
id  
 a  <type 'int'>
 b  <type 'int'>
```

But the type of `datetime`, post-aggregation, is `<M8[ns]`:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'datetime':get_earliest_minute}).datetime.dtype # dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929739/2799941) to the post linked above states that this happens because of a purposeful type coercion, which tries to maintain the type of the original Series object that underwent aggregation.  I've looked around a bit but couldn't find any solutions, other than [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929585/how-to-correctly-use-pandas-agg-function-when-running-groupby-on-a-column-of-typ#comment51771657_31929739) that suggested changing the type of the field to `object` before performing `groupby()`, e.g.,

```
df.datetime = df.datetime.astype(object)
df.groupby('id').agg({'datetime':get_earliest_minute})
```

and [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929585/how-to-correctly-use-pandas-agg-function-when-running-groupby-on-a-column-of-typ#comment51772258_31929739) which proposed to convert the output of the function to `float` before returning, e.g.,

```
def get_earliest_minute(tstamps):
    return float(tstamps.min().minute)
```

These workarounds do the job (although for some reason declaring `int()` does not escape type coercion like `float()` does), but is there a way to do these `groupby` manipulations on datetime objects without inserting explicit type conversions (i.e., either generalizing `<M8[ns]`->`object` or converting `int`->`float`)?  In particular, in a case in where multiple `agg()` functions are applied to `datetime`, with some functions which rely on datetime attributes and some which don't, this wouldn't succeed with a pre-groupby conversion.

Also, is there a reason why `float()` type conversion overrides the built-in type coercion, but `int()` does not?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as an FYI, the guy who answered the referenced question is the primary maintainer of pandas.  If he doesn't know the answer, the list people who might is extremely short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to stick with @Jeff on this one.  `agg` is doing what we all want.  It is attempting to preserve the `dtype` because it is intended to **aggregate** the values of a particular dtype.  **And** when I aggregate data of a particular `dtype` I expect that same `dtype` back...

...That said, you can very easily work around this with `apply`

***your problem***

```
def get_earliest_minute(tstamps):
    return tstamps.min().minute

df.groupby('id').agg({'datetime':get_earliest_minute})

                        datetime
id                              
a  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
b  1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
```

***workaround***

```
def get_earliest_minute(tstamps):
    return tstamps.min().minute

df.groupby('id').datetime.apply(get_earliest_minute)

id
a    1
b    3
Name: datetime, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I see your point, although I'd note that aggregation doesn't always return the original `dtype`, nor do we always want it to.  For example, `count` on a `str` field returns `int64`, and `mean` on an `int64` field returns `float64`.  Insofar returning matching `dtype`s isn't a strict rule, but instead a guiding principle, I can see a use case for something like an optional `dtype` argument that could force `agg()` to return a given `dtype`. The fact that I can currently do this manually for some types but not others (see examples above) feels a little arbitrary.

Comment: @andrew_reece that is `True`.  However, a lot of thought goes into these decisions.  Sometimes there is a bug, sometimes a feature has been missed because of neglect or lack of time, and sometimes it was an explicit decision made by the devs.  In this case, it was a decision made by the devs with regard to handling UDFs in `agg`.  I understand that it feels opaque.  But I can assure you that it isn't arbitrary.

Comment: Also, I can imagine a `dtype` being passed via the `dictionary` structure that is passed to `agg`.  It would require time to code, but I see that as an opportunity.  Don't know if I'd put it as high priority though.

Comment: @andrew_reece feel free to also up vote the answer. thank you